# 'git commit' and 'git status' contradicting

Tags: git

'git status' command gives this message:

> All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
>
> (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

But when I try to commit, I face an issue:

> git commit --amend --no-edit
>
> fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Well read the error message. You can't amend. Just make a regular commit.

Comment: Why do you want to use `--amend`?

Comment: My mistake I ignored last part of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started a merge action which is not finished. To finish it, call

```
git commit
```

Once your merge is finished, you can amend your last commit by typing

```
git commit --amend
```

The error message is pretty clear:

> fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the contradiction? The error message reported by `git commit` clearly says: you cannot amend because you are in the middle of a merge.

Run `git commit` without other arguments to conclude the merge.

You can add `--no-edit` if you don't want to modify the default commit message produced by `git merge` but `--amend` doesn't make any sense. You can amend an existing commit but since your merge failed, a commit has not yet be created (and consequently there is nothing to amend).